# Wrap lines in verbatim

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I just started to learn LaTeX, and I have to do some documentation with it.

However, the guy editing the TeX manuscript of the documentation before me didn't pay attention to word wrapping, so long lines aren't wrapped at all at the moment.

What is the best way to do auto-word-wrap (based on the margin, if possible)?

Improve/Edit: I use verbatim, and the word wrap I mean is the output-file

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Normal text is wrapped by default, is this code or something like that is in e.g. a `verbatim` environment? It might make it easier to answer if you could create a minimal code example demonstrating the behaviour (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: Do you mean words aren't wrapped in the `.tex` file, or in the output `.dvi` or `.pdf` file?

Comment: edited original post: I use verbatim and it's in the output file.
Example code can be supplied after the weekend

Answer (score 10):

One way would be to add the `listings` package and change the `verbatim` environments to `lstlisting`. Using find&replace in your editor should make that change quite quick. `listings` doesn't break lines by default either, so you need to add `breaklines=true` to the package options, or to `\lstset`. A small example is below, I also changed the `basicstyle` of `listings` to `\ttfamily`, so that it uses the monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
This is a very very very very very very long line that will run off the page in verbatim but not in lstlisting with breaklines=true.
\end{verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting}
This is a very very very very very very long line that will run off the page in verbatim but not in lstlisting with breaklines=true.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll try this monday, and I'll keep you posted